# oracle Insert into query is running slow over dblink

Tags: oracle, performance, append, insert-into, dblink

I have a a simple insert into query running

```
INSERT INTO SchemaA.tableA@server2 (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
 ) 
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 FROM SchemaA.tableA;
```

Here i cannot ftp/sftp the file to target server, only option is to somehow optimize query over dblink. Any pointers on how this can be done. Both are oracle servers.

Note: I tried adding append hint to the insert but dint make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with addition on hints on the query.

Will be helpful if you have gather stats on the target side.